# Progressive enhancement of anchor tags to avoid onclick="return false;"

Tags: ajax, events, onclick, xmlhttprequest

Unobtrusive JS suggests that we don't have any onclick attributes in our HTML templates.

```
<a href="/controller/foo/1">View Foo 1</a>
```

A basic progressive enhancement is to convert that anchor tag to use XHR to retrieve a DOM fragment.  So, I write JS to add an event listener for a."click" then make an XHR to a.href.

Alas, the browser still wants to navigate to "/controller/foo".  So, I write JS to dynamically inject a.onclick = "return false;".  Still unobtrusive (I guess), but now I'm paying the the cost of an **extra** event handler.

To avoid the cost of 2 event listeners, I could shove my function call into the onclick attribute

```
<a href="/controller/foo/1" onclick="myXHRFcn(); return false;">
```

But that's grodo for all sorts of reasons.

To make it more interesting, I might have 100 anchor tags that I want to enhance.  A better pattern is a single listener on a parent node that relies on event bubbling.  That's cool, but how do I short circuit the browser from navigating to the URL without this on every anchor node?

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Manipulating the href is not an option.  It must stay intact so the context menu options to copy or open in new page work as expected.

Comment: grodo?  Urbandictionary.com says "Extremely disgusting, usually the smell of a expletive expletive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` is likely what you are looking for (inside of the event handler where you are checking the `event.target` for the bubbled click)